# Panels problem modal form continuous loading

Tags: panels

I have a problem in panels.

When I choose layout and want to add content to it(also when I go to layout designer) nothing appear it just open the content window and continuously loading.

I am wait too long time didn't appear any thing.

I deleted the [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module and install it again ,clearing the cache ,changing browser but the problem still.

How can i solve it?

Comment: It will be an error causing the form to fail to load. You need to check your logs at `Admin > Reports > Recent log entries`, javascript console log and also server logs if nothing in former logs.

Comment: what is java script console and server logs

Comment: iam new in drupal and i dont know exactly what did u mean